# How to save time-based column to excel file with pandas?

Tags: pandas

I am using Pandas and used the diff() method on a column that have some date and time, the result is something like "3 days 02:54:21.750000"

This is how it is shown in jupyter notebook, but when I write the result in a excel file using:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('Result of analyse.xlsx') as writer:
gdata.to_excel(writer)
```

The result in the excel file for this column is like 3 
other info are omitted! how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see the "with" keyword in python, and the line ends in ':', then you are working with a context manager … and the follow-up lines that relate to it need to be indented.  Try this:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('Result of analyse.xlsx') as writer:
    gdata.to_excel(writer)
```

There are other ways to do it … see below link … I tend to prefer the way you wrote it, because context managers do some behind-the-scenes work, like saving/closing objects.

https://pythonexamples.org/pandas-write-dataframe-to-excel-sheet/

```py
# render dataframe as html
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df_marks.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
print('DataFrame is written successfully to Excel File.')
```